# how to enable fedex Free Shipping for all products in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.2, fedex

Magento 2.3.2 We use only FedEx for shipping. FedEx shipping is set up and working fine, rates are being calculated correctly. but we want to give free shipping to all customers. I all ready enable Free Method(ground)However, it is not being applied to FedEx.